# How can I insert a small image in a side note?

Tags: graphics, marginpar

I want to insert small images in sidenotes.
Is it possible (everything seems to)?
How could I do it?

Comment: A so called “minimum working example” would be nice. Show us, what you could achieve so far.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. You can use `\includegraphics` inside `\marginpar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{ctanlion}}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Another option would be to use `\marginnote` from the [`marginnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\marginnote{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{ctanlion}}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @AnibalVivaceta You're welcome! Don't forget (after a sensible wait) to accept the answer (up-voting and accepting are different actions); in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sidenotes` package that provides the proper environment and allows a caption, a label and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}% for sample images

\usepackage{sidenotes}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%

\end{document}
```

which leads to

[image: marginfigure]

the package also allows margintables and other stuff.